# How to write select query for taken Lastupdated rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql query can any one know how to get last updated records only from table using sql query.

**Table Schema:**
User Name | SoftwareName | Publisher

```
Scan time  | User Name | SoftwareName | Publisher | installed Date 
08-05-2016 04:44:00 AM | yyy       | Msoffice     | microsoft | 08-08-2016 09:34:00 PM 
08-06-2016 12:12:00 PM | xxx       | Msoffice     | microsoft | 08-08-2015 01:09:00 AM
08-06-2016 12:52:00 PM| xxx       | chrome       | google    | 08-07-2015 02:30:20 PM
```

Last Two rows are updated into 08-08-2016 i need to select query for last updated records only (08-08-2016)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (Vendor and Version)? 
Post your table definition and sample data.

Comment: Version? Please post your table definition, sample data and expected results.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: I think you'll need a timestamp field in order to query the last updated records.

Comment: |**Scan time | _User Name_  | _SoftwareName_ | _Publisher_ | _installed Date_** |
|08-05-2016 | yyy | Msoffice | microsoft | 08-08-2016 |
|08-06-2016 | xxx | Msoffice | microsoft | 08-08-2015 | 
|08-06-2016 | xxx | chrome | google | 08-07-2015 |
assume this is correctly updated at till date (date string is MM-dd-yyyy)
now and last two rows are inserted into today(08-08-2016). 
then how to get today records only.

Answer (score 1):

You want the records of the last day. So trim the time part from the datetime by casting to date, order by this, get the top 1 day with ties and you are done:

```
select top 1 with ties *
from mytable
order by cast([installed Date] as date) desc;
```

Comment: it may some lower date also inserted into that correct date then how will query those lower date and also the current date.

Comment: I don't understand. The query above gives you the latest date found in the table. If you want another date use a where clause. If you want the latest date plus a given date use two queries combined with `union all`. Does this answer your question?